# sum for duplicate rows without using group by

Tags: sql, sql-server

table named employee is given below:

```
id salary

10  100 
10  100
10  100
```

what should be the query in sql server 2012 to get following output

```
id salary 

10 300
10 300
10 300
```

that is sum of salary

Answer (score 3):

Based on sample data you can use window function :

```
select e.*, sum(sal) over ()
from emp e;
```

However, if you want the total salary for each `Id`s then include `partition` clause :

```
select e.*, sum(sal) over (partition by id) as tot_salary 
from emp e;
```

Answer (score 3):

You probably want:

```
select e.*, sum(e.sal) over (partition by e.id) as total_salary
from employee e;
```

That is, I'm guessing you want the sum per `id`.

Answer (score 2):

The right way is using `SUM` window function by `ID`

```
select t.id, sum(salary) over (PARTITION BY ID) salary  
from T t
```

Another way you can use correlate select

```
SELECT t1.id,(SELECT SUM(salary) FROM T tt where tt.id = t1.id) salary  
FROM T t1
```

[c# online](http://%20https://rextester.com/SCIQ74809)

Answer (score 0):

ANSI SQL

```
SELECT emp.id, emp2.salary
FROM emp INNER JOIN
     (SELECT id, SUM(salary) AS salary GROUP BY id) AS emp2
        ON emp.id = emp2.id
```